# Sarg *Squid Analyzer

Tags: squid

I cannot seem to install sarg successfully on CentOS6.

I did everything correctly, however, i got stock after running the command *make install*
It keeps on running the same lines over and over (almost 20mins) so i decided to stop the shell.

Here is the line showing after running *make install*

> && /bin/sh ./config.status po/Makefile.in po-directories
>   config.status: creating po/Makefile.in config.status: executing
>   po-directories commands config.status: creating po/POTFILES
>   config.status: creating po/Makefile make: Warning: File
>   `Makefile.in.in' has modification time 3.4e+08 s in the future cd .. \
>   && /bin/sh ./config.status po/Makefile.in po-directories
>   config.status: creating po/Makefile.in config.status: executing
>   po-directories commands config.status: creating po/POTFILES
>   config.status: creating po/Makefile make: Warning: File`
>   Makefile.in.in' has modification time 3.4e+08 s in the future cd .. \
>   && /bin/sh ./config.status po/Makefile.in po-directories
>   config.status: creating po/Makefile.in config.status: executing
>   po-directories commands config.status: creating po/POTFILES
>   config.status: creating po/Makefile make: Warning: File
>   `Makefile.in.in' has modification time 3.4e+08 s in the future cd .. \
>   && /bin/sh ./config.status po/Makefile.in po-directories
>   config.status: creating po/Makefile.in config.status: executing
>   po-directories commands config.status: creating po/POTFILES
>   config.status: creating po/Makefile make: Warning: File`
>   Makefile.in.in' has modification time 3.4e+08 s in the future cd .. \

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Is the system clock correct? It may not solve the problem, but will reduce warning output, making easier to read and debug.

Comment: You can use Ligthsquid it is, so, Squid Analyzer.

Comment: Timezone is setup properly. All other components on the machine is running perfectly aside from sarg.

Comment: @josecarlos - thanks for introducing Lightsquid! I like it.